# CSS : single ID selector vs. ID selector followed by more stuff

Tags: css

I just saw this in a css file:

```
#nav { margin: 13px 0 0 0; }

#nav ul li { margin: 0 20px 0 0; }
```

Doesn't the second #nav property definition cancel out the first #nav property definition?

(Also: am I saying this right? "Property definition"? What's the generally accepted term for the stuff inside the curly brackets?).

Comment: The first selects the element with `id='nav'` and styles it whereas the second selects a `li` element under a `ul` within an element with `id='nav'`.

Comment: That's [a declaration block](http://apps.workflower.fi/vocabs/css/en#declaration-block)

Comment: No, the second one will only overwrite the li inside the element whose Id is nav.

Comment: @Quentin Fantastic resource, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second definition does not "cancel" the first one; it selects the named elements that are descendants of  `nav` rather than selecting the `nav` element itself.

List items (`li`) that are descendants of unordered lists within an element with ID of `nav` will be styled by the second specification.  (Edited per Quentin's comment.)  The element with the ID  `nav` will use the first specification.  Elements within `#nav` may inherit from the first specification. For some properties, but not `margin`, inheritance is automatic.  The `font-family` property is an example.  The `margin` property can only be inherited through an explicit `margin: inherit;` specification.

If the code looked like this:

```
#nav { margin: 13px 0 0 0; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
#nav ul li { margin: 0 20px 0 0; }
```

Then the list items, and everything else within `nav` that did not have a `font-family` specification of its own would have a sans-serif font.

The things inside the curly braces are properties and values.  So, `margin` is a property, and the margin specifications are the values.  The things left of the curly braces are selectors.

Comment: "it is more specific" — While it is more specific, this has nothing to do with specificity since it selects a different element.

Comment: "Anything within #nav other than those list items will use the first specification" — No. Only `#nav` itself will use the first set of rules. Other elements inside it might *inherit* values for those properties.

Comment: @Quentin: You are correct about inheritance vs. direct application.  For the strict definition of specificity in CSS, you are also right.

Comment: @Quentin excellent points, thanks. I'm marking this answer correct because it answers my question and because Quentin's points help with additional clarification.

Comment: No, descendants of `#nav` will **not** inherit the `margin` setting, since that property is not inheritable. And no, the second definition is not "more specific" than the first; it addresses a different element, which is something entirely different than "specificity", a concept which applies to rules targeting the **same** element.

Comment: My original answer contained a couple of not-so-subtle errors, corrected in the comments.  Because it was accepted by OP, I have edited it to try to correct those errors instead of deleting it.  Thank you to those who corrected my errors in the comments.  See the edit history for the changes.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are applied to different elements, because they have different selectors.

The first rule applies to an element with id "nav". The second rule applies to an element li, that is a descendant of an element ul, that is descendant of an element with id "nav".

You can read about CSS Selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Comment: … and those selectors cannot match the same element (at least not with valid HTML).

Answer (score 0):

1) No. The second selector only applies to `li` which is descendant of `ul` which in turn is the descendant of `#nav`, while the first one only applies to the `#nav`

2) You call them as "style"